# How can I change the size of the frames in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I want to make the frame of the windows lower to fit more stuff into my screen. How can I do this in windows 7? XP was easy....

Answer (score 2):

If you mean multiple windows sized smaller so that they appear together, 
then open the windows you will work with, right-click on the task bar and 
select 'Show windows side by side'

Answer (score 0):

For individual windows, make sure that the windows is minimized while open (listed as "restore down") and you can change the side by grabbing the any corner while cursor is a double-sided arrow.